# baseUrl of tsconfig.json does not work

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

my project structure is
src/
  client/
  modules/
  server/
    app.ts

---

```
src/
  client/
  modules/
    DB/
  server/
    app.ts
tsconfig.json
```

i import a module using non-relative import in app.ts file

```
import * as DB from '@modules/DB';
```

because i do not want using `from "../modules/DB"`

and my tsconfig.json is

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "traceResolution": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "/"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
        "@modules/*": [
            "modules/*"
        ]
    }
},
"exclude": [
    "src/client/"
]
```

}

when i trace the resolution, got this

```
======== Module name '@modules/DB' was successfully resolved to '/Users/pengju/projects/pomelo-ts-starter/src/modules/DB/index.ts'. ========
```

it seems to successfuly import

but when compiled, vscode still got wrong with

```
[ts] Cannot find module '@modules/DB'.
```

at  `import * as DB from '@modules/DB';` in app.ts

then i check compiled app.js,
find `const DB = require("@modules/DB");`

the baseUrl and paths options, cannot change the "@modules/DB" to "../modules/DB"? then,what does they do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the TypeScript compiler does not update the path in your JS files and the JavaScript Engine knows nothing about your TypeScript config, what you specify in your tsconfig is only used "compile time", when you have compiled your TypeScript into JS you need to do the same job as the TS compiler did but to save the resolved path in the JS file.

Simply put, all JS files needs to be processed and the aliases replaced with "real" paths.

People often suggest WebPack which is a monster, there are a really simple tool called **tspath** which your run in your project directory, it will read your tsconfig.json and update the JS source files accordingly!

Install tspath an npm tool for resolving ts paths NOTE: tspath requires a very recent versison of node!

```
npm install -g tspath
```

After you have run the TypeScript compiler, from your project directory, run:

```
tspath
```

or

```
tspath -f
```

to skip the prompt!

Read more at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tspath

Comment: seems tspath is broken with recent JS features like spread or nullish coalescing. any other suggestions?
https://github.com/duffman/tspath/issues/34

Comment: Lots of alternatives to tspath: https://npmtrends.com/module-alias-vs-ts-transform-paths-vs-tsc-alias-vs-tsconfig-paths-vs-tsconfig-replace-paths-vs-tscpaths-vs-tspath